# DDD where to place a business rule like "A member can have only two bucket lists"

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Hi I’m currently playing around with a DDD (PHP) project and I’m running into to following question.

Let’s say that there is a business rule that says: A member can have only two bucket lists. The member object is widely used in the system.

My question is where to put this business rule?

Couple of options and my thoughts and concerns:

**Place it in the application service:**

Since it is a business rule I think it should be in the domain layer and not the application layer. Unless the rule is absolutely application specific, but even then I think it should go in a Domain service which is called by the application service.

**Place it in a Factory: (domain layer as either a simple factory or an abstract class)**

I could use the specification pattern to check my rule with an implementation that’s queries the DB to see if there’s already an existing bucket list for this user. A factories job is to create an object, so it feels like a proper place to check the rule. Although other team members could bypass the factory if they wanted to and this rule wouldn’t not be enforced.

**Place it in a domain service:**

The service would check the rule and then call the factory to build the object. But again it would be possible to bypass the the service.

Place it in the repository: (domain layer as an abstract class)

I could use the same approach as suggested for the factory here, but the job of the repository is to make it feel like a in memory collection. It feels wrong to check the rule here although it would make sure the rule is enforced when added something to the collection.

**Place it in the Entity:**

The check should go in the objects constructor or a setMemberId method which is called in it. This would make sure no invalid object can even be constructed which seems to me like the best situation, but the entity would have a dependency to a BucketListMustBeUniqueForMemberSpecification which feels wrong to me.

**Place it in a Value Object:**

MemberId is used by many other parts of the system so I would not place it there, but I could make an OwnerId value object and place the rule in there and feed it the membersId->id() as constructor input. The rule will be enforced but again there would be a dependency to BucketListMustBeUniqueForMemberSpecification which will be injected in the constructor :/

```
class SQLBucketListMustBeUniqueForMemberSpecification implements ...
{

    public function isSatisfiedBy($memberId)
    {
        // sql to try to find a bucket list of the members id

        return $bucketList ? false : true
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you modeled the bucket list? As an Aggregate?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes.

Comment: then why don't you give it the same ID as the user?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I see that my example scenario doesn't hold up. Sometimes you have a business rule that doesn't naturally fit in a value object or an Entity cause it may required a DB query to check the rule. I thought my example scenario was one of those cases. So I'm still wandering if my reasoning of each option is valid. I also read that all business rules should be explicit, so using a specification for instance communicates to my fellow developers that it is a business rule.

Comment: I'm also curious if you could use a specification inside a Value Object, Entity, Repository or Factory or is it considered a bad practice? and the reasons for why you could or could not ect..

Comment: you could use whatever that is not infrastructure or technology-specific.

Comment: So in the case of placing a specification in the Entity. Next to passing the value arguments to the constructor, you will also have to pass an implementation of specification. This feels off to me.

Comment: no, it isn't. As long as that specification is pure, with no side effects, you can even `new` it inside the entity. I do it like so. In this way the Entity has full control over the business rules. If you inject it, it may be decorated or moked and you don't want this.

Comment: just to be sure, can you give me a sample of a specification?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu added an SQL implementation, clearly you don't want to use the new keyword on this implementation inside your entity. So I'm still not sure

Comment: oh, no, if course not, I thought it is something pure. Even if you inject it in the Entity,  it would not be strongly consistent because the Entity does not own the data.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu so a reason not to put it in the entity is because it doesn't own the data. Which makes a lot of sense. But who does own it, the repository? if so, put the business rule in the add method? Notice btw that I changed the rule from one bucket list to two bucket lists per member.

Comment: yes, this makes sense. This is also known as "set validation" if you need more information. I like the simple idea of creating an unique index in the database (only for this kind of rule!).

Comment: in this way you get also strong consistency (if you simply check it in the add method there is the risk of concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

> "A member can have only two bucket lists"

Why not placing the rule within the `Member` itself? Unless you expect a very high number of associations that's a simple solution to protect the invariant.

```
class Member {
    ...
    final Set<BucketListId> bucketListIds;

    public Member(...) {
       bucketListIds = new HashSet<BucketListId>();
    }

    associateBucketLists(Set<BucketListId> bucketListIds) {
        if (bucketListIds.size() > 2) throw ...;
        bucketListIds.clear();
        bucketListIds.addAll(bucketListIds);
    }
}
```

You could also make it so that `BucketList` are created from `Member`s.

```
class Member {
    int bucketListCount = 0;

    public BucketList newBucketList(final BucketListId id, final BucketListDetails details) {
        if (bucketListCount == 2) throw ...;

        bucketListCount++;

        return new BucketList(id, this.id, details);
    }
}

class BucketList {
    final BucketListId id;
    final MemberId ownerId;
}

class MemberApplicationService {
    public void newBucketListFor(memberId, ...) {
        Member member = memberRepository.memberOfId(memberId);
        BucketList bucketList = member.newBucketList(...);
        bucketListRepository.add(bucketList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought of these approaches aswel, but the member aggregate is owner of a lot other aggregates. I read, in the ddd tackling complexity in the hearth of software, that it is best to avoid this approach because it wil clutter the member object.

Comment: @MennoHorde Do you have limits on all possible associations? You need to be specific when you ask questions, because the above design is certainly practical and elegant for the very case you mentioned and would most likely express the UL very well. There's no reason to be concerned with problems that you aren't currently facing (e.g. what if I need to constrain various disparate association types in the future?).